# How to use local storage to keep a users favorites list intact upon successive visits

Tags: iphone, web-applications, local-storage

So i have a web application I've developed using jquery and some jqtouch. I have javascript functions to clone list items to another "favorites" list if the user so chooses.

My question is how can I use localStorage to keep their favorites in the list when they come back into the web application?

I can't seem to find a straight forward answer..

Am I supposed to store the cloned values? or the original li elements? or the functions? 
I'm totally lost, so any help would be appreciated,
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [lawnchair](http://blog.westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) it is a js library for utilizing various local storage solutions on mobile devices.

Decent video tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/)